# Performing operations on aggregation

Tags: c++, oop

I have two classes: User and Book.

```
class User{
 private:
   string name ;
   int age;
   int id;
   string password;
   string email;
}

class Book {
   private:
     string title;
     string isbn;
     int id;
     string category;
     double averageRating;
     User author;
}
```

I'm asked to print the book only if it has an author, something similar to

```
if(author!="") {cout << ...etc}
```

This obviously isn't valid code since author is not a string. So, does anyone know what I could do instead?

Comment: And what **is** `author`? What does it mean in your code that a book doesn't have an author if `author` is always there? Take a look at `std::optional`.

Comment: @Evg author is a User. In the rest of the code when assigning the book info, I can choose one of the users (user object) I have previously defined to be the author. This means I can also leave the author empty and not assign any user(object) to it

Comment: What is _empty_ exactly? In C++ there are no special empty values like in some other programming languages. A default-constructed `User` can be regarded as empty, but that's probably a poor choice. Better, define `author` as `std::optional<User> author;` and then check `if (author) { ... }`.

Comment: @NayaCruiser: Your inequality check actually could be valid code if you implement the appropriate operator(s). But, I think that would be semantically unclear, so probably better to follow Evg's advice and use some other approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. One solution could be to use pointers. You can change the author to be a pointer and dynamically allocate it when required. You can do the NULL check to see if author is available or not and take the action accordingly.
2. You can use the std::optional feature from C++17 as mentioned by @Evg if you don't want to do the dynamic allocation. Please have a look at below link, could be usable:
   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stdoptional-how-when-and-why/